# modifying estimated value in loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, loss-function, backpropagation

I need some help with this problem. I even don't know if it's possible. I want to modify my loss function by changing the estimated value. If a have x as inputs then I have:

1. z=wx+b;
2. estimated_y1=max(0,z);
3. estimated_y2=k/estimated_y1;
4. loss_function=1/N*(y2_real-estimated_y2)²;

k is a constant.
How would this look in backpropagation if I want to predict y1?

Comment: is k a constant or something else ?

Comment: k is a constant